# /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/cElementTree.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Tags: centos, rhel, yum, python, elf

```
 yum update
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/cElementTree.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.4.3 (#1, Jan  9 2013, 06:47:03)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)]
```

I've tried doing some research and running clean on yum, but I still cannot get anything to install or update.

Is this a 32-64bit issue?

Comment: What is the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: 2.6.32-042stab093.4 x86_64

Comment: That error message *sounds* like a 32/64 thing. Where did that .so file come from (which package, or was it hand-installed?)

Comment: I have no idea actually. Just noticed yum was not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1. Downloading [Yum for CentOS 7](http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/centos/7.0.1406/x86_64/Packages/yum-3.4.3-118.el7.centos.noarch.html).
2. `rpm -ivh yum-*` from the save location.
3. Reissue `yum update`.  If it still complains, you need some version of [element-tree-x86_64](http://pkgs.repoforge.org/python-elementtree/).
4. Repeat number 2 with element-tree.